# Install git hook until npm install

Tags: git, npm, pre-commit-hook

I have a project with a `package.json` to load all the dev dependencies. Is there a way to install git commit hooks when after installing the project with `npm install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the [npm project](https://github.com/isaacs/npm), [`npm install`](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) itself will only install/clone the git repos, but also interpret the **[script section](https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html)**.

```
{ "scripts" :
  { "install" : "scripts/install.js"
  , "postinstall" : "scripts/install.js"
  , "uninstall" : "scripts/uninstall.js"
  }
}
```

You could declare a script in the `install` or `postinstall` step which would add your hooks in the cloned repos.